# FORTH writing to a "forth disk"

Tags: io, read-eval-print-loop, forth, gforth

You have a word in forth called `USE` which will create a file.

- `USE xxx  ( -- )`

  > Designate OS text file xxx as the "Forth disk."

However, it's not clear how you can write to that [FORTH Disk](https://www.forth.com/starting-forth/4-conditional-if-then-statements/) from within an interactive session. There are verbs such as `FLUSH` and `UPDATE` but neither of them see to do anything. I'm using gforth. I'm creating words in the session, and using them. I do not understand how a FORTH disk works in this context. It sounds like R's [`save.image()`](http://rfunction.com/archives/420), except I can't get anything to save. Could you supply a sequence of commands that result in something being written to the argument of `USE`?

Comment: This question should be dismissed because there was no decent effort. All information is available by looking up USE in the gforth documentation.

Answer (score 8):

FORTH was originally designed around the idea of a low-level system with a raw persistent storage system (a 'disk') and NO filesystem -- so no concept of files or folders or anything like that.  Instead, you read and write fixed size blocks on the disk, by block number.

Modern FORTH systems (like gforth) have support for filesystems, but ALSO still have support for the low-level raw 'disk' that is accessed by block number.  Since gforth usually runs on an OS with a filesystem and no low-level disk access (without superuser permissions), to use the low-level disk block words, you need to give a file<sup>1</sup> to use as the underlying storage for the raw disk blocks -- and that is what the `USE` word does.

---

If you want to understand how to *use* the low-level block I/O words in FORTH, you need to read a forth book about it, but basically, you use `BLOCK` to read a block into a buffer, `UPDATE` to mark a buffer as modified, and `FLUSH` to flush modified buffers to the disk.  From the ANSI forth spec, you find:

> 7.6.1.0800 BLOCK ( u -- a-addr )
> a-addr is the address of the first character of the block buffer assigned to mass-storage block u.
> An ambiguous condition exists if u is not an available block number.
> If block u is already in a block buffer, a-addr is the address of that block buffer.
> If block u is not already in memory and there is an unassigned block buffer, transfer block u
> from mass storage to an unassigned block buffer. a-addr is the address of that block buffer.
> If block u is not already in memory and there are no unassigned block buffers, unassign a block
> buffer.
>  If the block in that buffer has been UPDATEd, transfer the block to mass storage and
> transfer block u from mass storage into that buffer. a-addr is the address of that block buffer.
> At the conclusion of the operation, the block buffer pointed to by a-addr is the current block
> buffer and is assigned to u.
> 7.6.1.2400 UPDATE ( -- )
> Mark the current block buffer as modified. An ambiguous condition exists if there is no
> current block buffer.
> UPDATE does not immediately cause I/O.
> See: 7.6.1.0800 BLOCK, 7.6.1.0820 BUFFER, 7.6.1.1559 FLUSH, 7.6.1.2180 SAVE-BUFFERS.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>On a system like Linux with appropriate permissions, you can use `USE` with a raw disk device to get something like the original intent.</sub>

Comment: Very cool information, let's say I do give a file with `USE`. How can I write anything to that file from within forth? I've updated the question to be more explicit.

Answer (score 3):

You can write your own words to manipulate blocks. But for the first time you can use simple block editor from the `gforth` (https://github.com/forthy42/gforth/blob/master/blocked.fb). I'm use it in the following way. First you need to load it:

`use blocked.fb` - this file is use file `blocked.fb` as forth disk;

`1 load` - load the vocabulary;

`editor` - this is change vocabulary to newly created.

Now you can modify file with words defined in vocabulary `editor`. Here example:

```
use tmp
0 l
0 t : one-plus-two   1 2 + .  ;
flush
```

Brief explanation of some words (from blocked.f):

`a` - goes to marked position

`c` - moves cursor by n chars

`t` - goes to line n and inserts

`i` - inserts

`d` - deletes marked area

`r` - replaces marked area

`f` - search and mark

`il` - insert a line

`dl` - delete a line

`qx` - gives a quick index

`nx` - gives next index

`bx` - gives previous index

`n` - goes to next screen

`b` - goes to previous screen

`l` - goes to screen n

`v` - goes to current screen

`s` - searches until screen n

`y` - yank deleted string

Answer (score 1):

> Could you supply a sequence of commands that result in something being written to the argument of `USE`?

An example of update a block content programmatically:

```
: write-block ( sd.text u.block -- )
  over 1024 u> abort" too long content for a block" 
  buffer ( c-addr.text u.text addr.buffer )
  dup 1024 blank  swap move
  update
  save-buffers
;

use test.blk
s" test passed"  1 write-block
cr 1 list
```

Take into account that the address of a block buffer returned by `block` or `buffer` **is transient**, with very weak guarantees to a program. It becomes invalid after next performing of `block`, `buffer`, `list`, or `load`, parsing, displaying characters, etc, — see [7.3.2 Block buffer regions](https://forth-standard.org/standard/block#block:buffers).